# How can I fix a nested while-loop that runs infinitely?

Tags: c++, infinite-loop

So I have another problem that I am running into. I have been trying to fix this for about an hour with no luck. I cannot get this nested while loop to work. The code should be putting in lines according to the input but currently it goes on forever.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void PrintLines(char characterValue, int characterCount, int lineCount);

// I'm going to have to change char characterValue to int characterValue
// will this still work if they are in seperate files?

void PrintLines(char characterValue, int characterCount, int lineCount)
    {
        while (lineCount--)                 //This is the problem
        {
            while (characterCount--)
            {
                cout << characterValue;
            }
            cout << "\n";
        }


    }

int main()
{

    char Letter;
    int Times;
    int Lines;

    cout << "Enter a capital letter: ";
    cin >> Letter;
    cout << "\nEnter the number of times the letter should be repeated: ";
    cin >> Times;
    cout << "\nEnter the number of Lines: ";
    cin >> Lines;

    PrintLines(Letter, Times, Lines);



    return 0;
```

When I do this to check if it works properly. I see that it does...

```
        while (lineCount--)                 //This is to check
        cout << "\n%%%";
        {
            while (characterCount--)
            {
                cout << characterValue;
            }
        }
```

It prints :(If Lines = 4 and Times = 3 and Letter = A)

```
%%%
%%%
%%%
%%%AAA
```

Comment: For the record, an hour isn't that long. Programming problems may take days or even weeks to solve. Patience is a virtue. Artificial time limits such as that imposed by a badly-designed educational course are out of the scope of programming Q&A.

Comment: @texasbruce: No, the problem *is* here.

Comment: I understand. I can usually get most of it but I'm not sure why but I'm just not getting certain things.

Comment: _Being human_ is probably most of it. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    while (lineCount--)                 //This is the problem
    {
        while (characterCount--)
        {
            cout << characterValue;
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }
```

After the first iteration of lineCount, characterCount is negative. You keep decrementing it, and it will never reach zero again until it overflows.

Do:

```
    while (lineCount--)                 //This is the problem
    {
        int tmpCount = characterCount;
        while (tmpCount--)
        {
            cout << characterValue;
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }
```

Comment: Sorry; I hadn't seen the tag. (And hadn't it been deprecated?)

Comment: I'm not using anyone's code other than my own. After outputting the character value and lineCount I am thinking of what to do next.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you seem to expect that `characterCount` gets its original value for each iteration of the loop. However, since you change it in the inner loop, it gets to `-1` and it takes quite a while before you get back to `0`. You need to keep the original `characterCount` around, e.g., using using a variable specifically for each loop.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of "%%%", print something useful, like the values of `characterCount` and `lineCount`. Then you'll see what your loop is doing and, ultimately, what you've done wrong.

Comment: In this instance, since other posters have just done all of this for you, you'd have seen `characterCount` start at `-1` for the second iteration of the outer loop and immediately spotted the problem. It would have been invaluable debugging experience.

Comment: I see. Your post was first and I did try it because I rather figure it out with a little advice rather than using  someones work.

Answer (score 0):

This should fix your code. Your `characterCount` gets decremented below zero, and I prevented this:

```
void PrintLines(char characterValue, int characterCount, int lineCount)
{   
    while (lineCount--)                 
    {   
        int cCount = characterCount;//This was the problem

        while (cCount--) // and this fixes it
        {   
            cout << characterValue;
        }   

        cout << "\n";
        cCount = characterCount ; 
    }   

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless you're constrained to use a nested loop, it's probably simpler to do something like this:

```
// Beware: untested in the hopes that if you use it, you'll need to debug first
std::string line(Times, Letter);

std::fill_n(std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, "\n"), 
            lineCount,
            line);
```

Comment: Have not learned that yet. Thanks for the information though.